# Material Has Dark Areas that Move as Object Moves When Rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, texture-coordinates

I'm rendering video of a tress of hair moving. The issue I'm having is that when rendered as the tress moves from side to side there are darker areas that seem to change when the tress moves. I don't know if they are shadows or the actual material though. The top of the tress is also an orange-ish color

I'm also having an issue with the 3D view not looking like the material preview but I don't have any light in my scene to cause this.

Attached are the material node, 3D view, and the final render.
[image: Material Nodes]
[image: UI]
[image]

Comment: Please attach blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: I pressed "flag" as needs more details from author, but it jumped under "close" section. Hmm

Comment: @vklidu for some reason I cant upload the .blend file

Comment: From your description I can't say why, so I can't help with that. Use any servis you know (without need to register) so I can try to upload here for you (or somebody, because Im leaving for a week tomorrow).